# Como aplicar border-shadow em um elemento pai e um filho com hover?

Tags: css

Estou fazendo um um curso de CSS e me surgiu essa dúvida:

Como faço para aplicar um mesmo border-shadow no elemento pai (.plan--highlighted) e no elemento filho (.plan__annotation) ao passar o mouse sobre o elemento pai?

```
<article class="plan plan--highlighted">
          <h1 class="plan__annotation">RECOMMENDED</h1>
          <h1>PLUS</h1>
          <h2>$29/month</h2>
          <h3>For ambitious projects.</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>5 Workspaces</li>
            <li>Unlimited Traffic</li>
            <li>100GB Storage</li>
            <li>Plus Support</li>
          </ul>
          <div>
            <button>CHOOSE PLAN</button>
          </div>
          </article>
```

CSS

```
  `.plan--highlighted {
  background: #19b84c;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;}`

 `.plan--highlighted:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}`

 `.plan__annotation {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #19b84c;
  font-style: bold;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 8px;}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta adicionar uma nova regra ao `.plan--highlighted:hover` acrescentando a classe do elemento filho que você quer aplicar a mesma propriedade:

```
.plan--highlighted:hover, 
.plan--highlighted:hover .plan__annotation { /* hover na classe do elemento filho */
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado @Sam